# How to reuse a function that is in between a chain of thens (promise related)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple func that chains a few times

```
return config.load()
    .then(function() {
        //first duplicate code block
    })
    .then(function() {
        //the start of my unique block
        return foo.bar()
            .then(function(trace) {
                //unique code
            })
            .then(function(tree) {
                //more unique code
            });
    })
    .then(function() {
        //second duplicate code
    })
    .then(config.save)
    .then(function() {
        //more duplicate for part 2
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        //more duplicate for part 2
    });
```

The middle "then" you see above is the only part that is different in my 2 different cases. I'm looking to see how I can refactor this to keep it DRY

Comment: Holy lord, this should be made a Prime Example of Callback Hell.

Comment: @TwiStar "Callback Hell" are nested callbacks (forms a triangle in code due to indentation). Promises alleviate that by making the code appear linear, just like this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare them outside, and just reference them in the promise chain

```
// Declare reusables
function dupe1(arg1,arg2,...,argN){...}
function dupe2(arg1,arg2,...,argN){...}

// Go about our normal business, with functions replaced with a reference
return config.load()
  .then(dupe1)
  .then(function() {
    //the start of my unique block
    return foo.bar()
    .then(function(trace) {
        //unique code
    })
    .then(function(tree) {
        //more unique code
    });
  })
  .then(dupe2)
  .then(config.save)
  .then(dupe2)
  .catch(dupe2);
```

Comment: how can I /should I pass args to dupe1() inside the then? as I'm not invoking it manually from what I can see

Comment: I see arg1/2 at the top, but you never pass them in when you invoke it below .then(dupe1)

Comment: @ToranBillups They just get called by `then`. Go try it.

Comment: interesting - didn't see that one coming :)

Comment: logging I seem to get undefined in the extracted func

Comment: does this depend on the promise library used possibly? I'm using rsvp in this example

Comment: @ToranBillups You should see no difference just by pulling out the function and sending in a reference.

Comment: agreed - but would a CJS module scope differently than you'd expect in the browser?

Comment: @ToranBillups Just make sure those functions are declared in the same scope as that code. Otherwise, it might be missing some variables if you put it too far outside.